# Error: Could not resolve to a component implementation

Tags: apache-flex, module, flex4

I have a module that seems to work fine with spark components in it but when I try to load my own it gives me this error.

```
Error: Could not resolve <views:DisplayList> to a component implementation.
```

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
          xmlns:views="views.*"

          width="400" height="300" 

          >

    <views:DisplayList width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:Module>
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the error you were receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did four things

- Project > Clean
- Closed other projects
- Restarted Flash Builder
- Opened a project properties of a library that had similarly named classes (different packages, same class name) and unchecked include classes.

One of those fixed it. I think Project > Clean. If it happens again I'll refine this answer.

**UPDATE**:
Running Project > Clean > Clean all Projects worked (while selecting only Clean current project did not).

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem after opening a project that had been created using Flex SDK 4.x but had been updated to 4.6.0.  I tried the above 4 steps but to no avail.  I then tried changing the Flex SDK in Project->Properties->Flex Compiler from the "Use default SDK (currently "4.6.0") back to "Use a specific SDK: Flex 3.6" (which was the only other one in my SDK list). Naturally, that showed the same errors. Then I set it to "Use a specific SDK: Flex 4.6.0" and all the errors went away!

I may have been able to just set it to "4.6.0" without having to first set it to "3.6" but wanted to report exactly what I had done.  Something about setting it "specifically" rather than leaving the "default" button checked allowed Flex to update its internal references to the correct SDK after my Flex update I believe.  I hope this saves someone some time and trouble.

Comment: I have done that before as well and had it help other situations. I think it rebuilds the Flash Builder projects / properties cache. Eclipse uses a cache to speed up access to project properties and methods. I don't know the details but heard this description like this from a Flex SDK engineer. Glad it helped fix this.